# XSD schema not validating in basex

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, basex

I am tasked with adding type="DeptType" to an xsd file and validating it in basex against an xml document. I have validated both in notepad++ but I get an error in basex when trying to validate.

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="dept" type="DeptType" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:extension>
                     </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="staff" type="StaffType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="deptKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="dept"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:key name="staffKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="staff"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
    </xs:key>
    <!-- keyref does not work with simpleContent -->
    <xs:keyref name="staffdeptref" refer="deptKey">
        <xs:selector xpath="staff"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@dept"/>
    </xs:keyref>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="StaffType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="staff" type="StaffType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="dept"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<root  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <dept id="i1"><name>it</name></dept>
    <dept id="i2"><name>law</name></dept>
    <staff id="i2"><name>steve</name></staff>
    <staff id="i3" dept="i2"><name>jerry</name></staff>
</root>
```

basex validation
validate:xsd("doc-4xsd.xml")

The error I get is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mVYZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of this part:

```
<xs:element name="dept" type="DeptType" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
```

Since the `complexType` is defined within the `element`, you shouldn't specify the `type` attribute. I think the `type` attribute is just for referencing types elsewhere in the schema. So it's either:

```
<xs:element name="dept" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:complexType>
```

or

```
<xs:element name="dept" type="DeptType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

<xs:complexType name="DeptType">
```

but not both.

Comment: Thank you but when I try the second one I get the following error "Attribute 'name' cannot appear in element 'complexType'."
The first code is the original code where I got the original error.

Comment: Re the second one, are you sure the complex type is no longer nested within the element but instead below "schema" (notice the close tag at the end of "element")? Re the first, the difference is the removal of the "type" attribute.

Comment: @Jacko, [this link](https://www.xfront.com/GlobalVersusLocal.html) may help describe the different approaches to schema design, and whether to use local or global types.